# Nested aura iterator initializing the same child component twice with different GlobalIds

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration

I have a record listing, created by 3 aura components, that call each other using aura:iteration loops:

- listCmp: root cmp, represents the list itself
- recordCmp: represents each record of the list
- fieldCmp: represents each field of the record

In this example, each of them has an initialization method that logs some identification info on the console, and the root component populates the record list by clicking a button. The record list data itself is a list of a single record object, that contains a list of a single field object, that contains an attribute and a value. The full thing is like this:

[image]

The first time the record list is populated by clicking the button, it executes (in this order) the fieldCmp init method, and then the recordCmp init method. But the ***second*** time the record list is populated it runs the same 2 methods as before plus the fieldCmp init method again at the end, creating some undesirable behaviors.

This repeated execution seems to come from ***another*** instance of the fieldCmp component since the GlobalIds logged are different, but i have no idea why does that happen or how to prevent it.

After the initialization has been completed, only one field appears on the screen, and if I check its GlobalId it matches with the GlobalId of the first init method.

Here is the flow of tests i did, and the output on the console:

[image]

1. The root component loads
2. record list is populated with the button (notice only 2 init executions)
3. I manually double checked the fieldCmp GlobalId, and it matches
4. record list is populated again (notice 1ts and 3rd lines, same init but different GlobalId)
5. I double checked again the fieldCmp GlobalId, and it matches with the first execution

Can anyone bring some light to help me solve this problem, in order to instantiate and execute these unit methods only the desirable times?

Thank you!